# Will GC clean up my object if I point to a method in it?

Tags: python, methods, garbage-collection

Assume I have:

```py
class foo:
 def bar(self):
  pass
```

Then I create an instance of the class,
and then lets assume I am saving the method in a variable:

```py
x = foo().bar
```

Can the Garbage Collector by any chance clean the object because I am not pointing to him even tho I am pointing to a method of it?

Comment: This is not at all clear.  First, your "saving" assignment is incorrect.  I think you mean `x = foo.bar` (no parentheses).  Second, how does assigning an alias for an instance method affect the references to one of the instances?  I suspect that you need a clearer understanding of classes, instances, and garbage collection.  Otherwise, please clarify your question.

Comment: @Prune I meant  saving the method itself of some instance of the class ```foo```

Comment: @Prune What exactly was wrong with `foo().bar`?

Comment: Nothing; I just figured out what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo().bar` creates a `foo` instance and then a `bar` method that's bound to that instance. That binding prevents the instance from becoming garbage as long as there's a reference to the method object.

Theoretically the implementation could notice that `bar` never actually references `self`, so it doesn't really need to be bound. But Python 3.6.3 doesn't do this.  You can access the instance using the `__self__` attribute.

```
x = foo().bar
print(x) # <bound method foo.bar of <__main__.foo object at 0x1042269e8>>
print(x.__self__) # <__main__.foo object at 0x1042269e8>
```